# Ionic views are different in browser and simulator

Tags: ionic-framework

I designed an app, but there's a difference in the placement of the search box below the sub-header when run on both browser and emulator. Any idea on why is this happening ?
[image: App on emulator][image: App on browser]

HTML Template

```html
<ion-header-bar style="color: black; border-bottom: 2px solid #ed1b24 "class="bar bar-light bar-subheader">
    <div class="title">
     Home
    </div>

     <div class="buttons">
      <button style="color: #ed1b24;" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-shuffle-strong" ng-click="isClick=!isClick"></button>
     </div>

   </ion-header-bar>

   <div class="fixed-header my-video"  >
          <label class="item-input-wrapper search-box-label">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
          </label>
      </div>
<ion-content class="ion-content-below-my-video has-footer">.....
```

CSS

```css
.fixed-header{
      margin-top: 88px;
  /* @in height,
   put your content below the header bar.
  */
}

.my-video
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ed1b24;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.ion-content-below-my-video{
      margin-top: 40px!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML template for this page? At least up to the part that contains the search bar.

Comment: @maninak I edit the question. Please check.

Comment: I guess you mean "on both emulator and browser"..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a CSS discrepancy between the iOS webview and your browser.

**You shouldn't use custom input field for the search, it's *strongly* recommended to use the existing [`<ion-searchbar>`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) element.**

Also make sure you are not running a very old iOS version in your emulator. Consider bundling [`WKWebview`](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/wkwebview-v3-0-0/82814) into your app if you haven't already. iOS applications, especially on older devices benefit  greatly from that, although it increases your cordova build bundle size significantly.

Comment: I added the WKWebview plugin as you mentioned, but still there is a difference in both the emulator and web browser view :(

Comment: @AndrewJeromeBernard check out the edit I made on my answer above. I'm positive this is your solution.